# Angular Material: Create component that can be accessed by the 'parent element'?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

### Note

The title of this post may not sound relavent with the content of this post, because I've no idea how to say it in a single sentence. Also, sorry if somebody else already asked this question, but I'm unable to find any.

### The Situation

So here's my problem, I have a **homepage** component which has a Angular Material Grid List:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" gutterSize="5px" class="{{ isMobile ? 'mobile' : '' }}">
     <app-grid-section title="My Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
     <app-grid-section title="Follower's Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
     <app-grid-section title="Following's Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And I created a **GridSection** component, and the template looks like this:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>{{ title }}</mat-grid-tile-header>

    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

### The Problem

When I view the page, it's pure blank. I run "Inspect" in chrome and I see the elements there, but their not showing on the page. Is it because `mat-grid-tile` must be a direct descendent of `mat-grid-list`? I hope not, because I was planning for the `GridSection` component to be like a "grid tile template".

I'm using the Angular CLI, Angular v10 or 8, and Visual Studio Code as the text editor.

Link on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q452c8?file=src/app/homepage/homepage.component.html

Comment: Can you create some plunker or something like that to test it?

Comment: @Ferrmin I don't know if it's my computer, but plunker to forever to render Angular Projects.

Comment: @Fermín I've decided to post my issue on StackBlitz instead. Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q452c8?file=src/app/homepage/homepage.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to make it work. Maybe this is related to some angular material issue.

I forked your stackblitz here: https://angular-ivy-nvdxmx.stackblitz.io

What I did:

grid-section.component.ts

```
<mat-grid-tile-header>{{ title }}</mat-grid-tile-header>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

homepage.component.html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" gutterSize="5px">
<mat-grid-tile>
    <app-grid-section title="My Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile>
    <app-grid-section title="Follower's Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile>
    <app-grid-section title="Following's Stuff">Some Content</app-grid-section>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatButtonModule, MatGridListModule],
  entryComponents: [HomepageComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomepageComponent, GridSectionComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This now is working. Please, let me know if you need something else!